# Optimizing SELECT IN () SQL query with SELECT subquery that returns many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I just discovered that one page in my app loads very slowly because of a certain SQL query, among many.

I have read [this document about subquery optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html) but it seemed to outline how MySQL optimizes subqueries, and not how I can optimize my queries. I did try some ideas I got from the document, to no avail.

This is currently my slow query. I simplified the table and column names for readability:

```
SELECT
    a.one, a.two, a.three, a.four,
    b.*,
    a.id,
    b.id,
    c.one, c.id,
    d.one,
    f.one
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
JOIN c ON c.id = b.c_id
JOIN e ON b.e_id = e.id
JOIN d ON d.id = e.d_id
JOIN f ON f.id = b.f_id
WHERE a.id IN (
    SELECT a_id FROM b WHERE a_id IS NOT NULL AND g_id = 95
)
```

The SELECT subquery currently returns 750+ rows, which I think causes the delay for the parent query. The whole query takes 25 seconds.

How may I optimize this query?

Comment: Which table is `g_id` in?

Comment: `IN ( SELECT ... )` optimizes poorly.  `WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )` often works faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to 5.6.5, MySQL would not materialize the subquery. This means that for each record on the join, it would run the following correlated query:

```
SELECT  1
FROM    b
WHERE   a_id IS NOT NULL
        AND g_id = 95
        /* optimizer added */
        AND a_id = a.id
LIMIT   1
```

, with an additional condition added by the optimizer.

From 5.6.5 on, MySQL is able to materialize the results of the `IN` subquery into a temporary table and join it as any other.

If you are using MySQL prior to 5.6.5, you can try rewriting your condition as a join:

```
SELECT  a.one, a.two, a.three, a.four,
        b.*,
        a.id,
        b.id,
        c.one, c.id,
        d.one,
        f.one
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT a_id
        FROM    b
        WHERE   a_id IS NOT NULL
                AND g_id = 95
        ) bi
JOIN a ON a.id = bi.a_id
JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
JOIN c ON c.id = b.c_id
JOIN e ON b.e_id = e.id
JOIN d ON d.id = e.d_id
JOIN f ON f.id = b.f_id
```

and of course index all relevant fields properly.

Comment: I got your suggestion to work by adding this at the very end: `WHERE b.g_id = 95`, i.e. I needed to filter the outer query too

Comment: Out of curiosity, would a `WHERE EXISTS()` work well on MySQL too?

Comment: @deroby: it would, yes